# scala, general purpose transform function for all objects

Tags: scala

I'd like to have something as follows:

```
val onlyNice = true;

val users: List[String] = getNames()
val result = users
  .filter(_.contains("john")
  .map(._toUpperCase)
  .filter(p => isNice)   // here i would need to apply this filter only if `onlyNice` is true
  .map(p => countryOf(p));
```

that is, I want to apply the `isNice` filter only if `onlyNice==true`.
I could do it as follow:

```
val result = users
  .filter(_.contains("john")
  .map(._toUpperCase)
  .filter(p => !onlyNice || isNice)
  .map(p => countryOf(p));
```

but this would slow down performance, because we are traversing all the list even if onlyNice is false.

we could do as follows:

```
val tmp = users
  .filter(_.contains("john")
  .map(._toUpperCase)

val tmp2 = if (onlyNice) tmp.filter(isNice) else tmp

val result = tmp2.
  .map(p => countryOf(p));
```

but this is more difficult to read.

This seems a good generalized solution to me:

```
implicit class ObjectHelper[A](o: A) {
  def transform[B](f: A => B): B = f(o)
}

val result = users
  .filter(_.contains("john")
  .map(._toUpperCase)
  .transform(list => if (onlyNice) list.filter(isNice) else list)
  .map(p => countryOf(p));
```

what do you think?

is this `transform` function already implemented in the standard scala library somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `transform` is essentially a flipped form of function application.

I don't know of an implementation in the standard library, but it is implemented in the Scalaz library as the `|>` operator, e.g.

```
import scalaz.syntax.id._

users |> (list => if (onlyNice) list.filter(isNice) else list)
```

Note that because in this case, the function is of type `A => A` rather than `A => B` (i.e. it is `List[String] => List[String]`), you can equivalently use the `identity` function, e.g.

```
users |> (if (onlyNice) (_.filter(isNice)) else identity)
```

Comment: the example does not compile (error "not found: value |>"). I added the dependency to scalaz-core_2.10 7.0.0, and import scalaz._  do I need something else to make it compile? and, is there an API doc? I only found the the general doc page at https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz

Comment: You'll need to import an implicit from `scalaz.syntax.id._`. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: great, thanks! is there the api doc somewhere? how should i have find out about syntax.id?

Comment: For the API docs, try http://bit.ly/scalaz-7-docs. There is a good explanation of the syntax implicits at http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz-day13